# How do I align the text in the middle of the image in this case?

Tags: css, text-alignment

I have this HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:12px;">
            <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" href="#">
            <img width="80" height="80" class="recent-thumbnail" title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lano_Beach_-_Savai%27i,_2007.jpg">Blogartikel Nummer 2</a>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.</div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:12px;">
            <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" href="#">
            <img width="80" height="80" class="recent-thumbnail" title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lano_Beach_-_Savai%27i,_2007.jpg">Blogartikel Nummer 1</a>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.</div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There is an image on the left and on the right we have a link with some text below. I want to align the text on the right in the middle onf the image. I tried style="vertical-align:middle;", but this will not align the full text, just a part.

How can I do that?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wNFTs/

Thanks! :)

Comment: do you just want to align the link or div below it as well??

Comment: The full text including the div, not just the link

Comment: Then just put float: left in your class called 'recent-thumbnail'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `text-align`

```
 text-align:center
```

Make a `CSS` class and do:

```
.center-text {
    text-align:center;
}

<span class="center-text"> Blogartikel Nummer 2</span>
<div class="center-text"> Lorem Ipsum </div>
```

Since span are not block elements you may have to apply: `display: inline-block` attribute to the span.

http://jsfiddle.net/K6pSK/6/

Comment: I want to align the full text, not just the link.

Comment: @user1856596 - apply the style to the div too.  I'd suggest making a class. I will update my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap them in containers and set the containers to be `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:12px;">
                <div class="image">
                    <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" href="#">
                        <img width="80" height="80" class="recent-thumbnail" title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lano_Beach_-_Savai%27i,_2007.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" href="#">Blogartikel Nummer 2</a>
                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:12px;">
                <div class="image">
                    <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" href="#">
                        <img width="80" height="80" class="recent-thumbnail" title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lano_Beach_-_Savai%27i,_2007.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" href="#">Blogartikel Nummer 1</a>
                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                    eirmod tempor invidunt.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.image, .info {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw5rG/1/)

**Suggestion:**

You can also get away from tables entirely, since you are not really displaying tabular data, by wrapping each item in its own container instead.

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="image">
        <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" href="#">
            <img width="80" height="80" class="recent-thumbnail" title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lano_Beach_-_Savai%27i,_2007.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" href="#">Blogartikel Nummer 2</a>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="image">
        <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" href="#">
            <img width="80" height="80" class="recent-thumbnail" title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lano_Beach_-_Savai%27i,_2007.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 1" href="#">Blogartikel Nummer 1</a>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
            eirmod tempor invidunt.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.image, .info {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw5rG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding a table inside href. But this not the best method.

```
<tr>        <td style="padding-bottom: 12px;">
                            <a title="Blogartikel Nummer 2" href="#" style="vertical-align: middle">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img width="80" height="80" class="recent-thumbnail" title="Blogartikel Nummer 2"
                                                src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lano_Beach_-_Savai%27i,_2007.jpg">
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="middle">
                                            Blogartikel Nummer 2
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                            <div>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                                tempor invidunt.</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```